# Magento 2.3.4: Not able to search admin grids

Tags: magento2, admin, knockoutjs, magento2.3.4

Recently upgraded from 2.3.1 to 2.3.4-p2 and now we're not able to use the keyword search above admin grids like Catalog > Products, Sales > Orders, etc.

We can still use the filter boxes, but the keyword search is not working and receive the following console errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: focused is not defined

[image]

We've tried running the following but still does not work:

```
bin/magento s:d:c
bin/magento s:s:d -f
bin/magento i:rei
bin/magento c:f
```

Any ideas what else this could be?